# How to Update Custom Product Total Price with Discount

Tags: magento-1.9, price, upgrade, custom

How to change Product custom price with same product id in Magento.
My Website URL is http://zohard.com/kanzy_new/index.php/customize-bundle/

I have added product in bundle list and apply discount by product added as a position wise discount,I need to update cart price same as total for this bundle.
Thanks in advanced.